# Have ansible vars be a range of numbers

Tags: ansible

I currently have a ansible script as such

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: False
  vars:
    http_port: 3014
  tasks:

  - name: Supervisor stop {{ http_port }}
    become: true
    supervisorctl:
      name: yt{{ http_port }}
      state: stopped
```

But I need to do this for say ports 3000 through 3100. How would I have it dynamically change the http_port variable to loop through that many numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [range](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-sequence). For example.

```
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: False
  vars:
    http_port_from: 3000
    http_port_to: 3100

  tasks:

  - name: "Supervisor stop from {{ http_port_from }} to {{ http_port_to }}"
    become: true
    supervisorctl:
      name: "yt{{ item }}"
      state: stopped
    loop: "{{ range(http_port_from, http_port_to + 1)|list }}"
```